# Sum of a subset of a set of cardinality n being a multiple of n

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a set of cardinality n, how do I know that there exists a subset that the sum of the elements in the set are a multiple of n.

$\forall S\subseteq \mathbb{Z} : |S|=n$

$\exists A \subseteq S : \sum_i A_i = nk, k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Based on what you've written, you could take $k=0$ and $A=\varnothing$, but I'm supposing that's not what you're looking for...

Comment: Can you add what have you tried, please?

Comment: Can you do it when $N=2?$  $N=3$?

Answer (score 5):

(This is not original.)

List them in some order
$(A_i)_{i=1}^n$
and let
$B_j
=\sum_{i=1}^j A_i
$
for
$j=1$ to $n$.

If all the $B_j$ are distinct
mod $n$,
then, since there are $n$
of them,
one of then
is $\equiv 0 \bmod n$.

If two of them are equal
$\bmod n$,
say
$B_k \equiv B_j$
where $j < k$,
then,
since
$B_j
=\sum_{i=1}^j A_i
$
and
$B_k
=\sum_{i=1}^k A_i
$,
subtracting these,
$0 
\equiv B_k-B_j
\equiv\sum_{i=j+1}^k B_j
$
so the sum of
$(A_i)_{i=j+1}^k$
is divisible by $n$.